# Finding And Analyzing A Deadlock happened before some days. (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

After searching in different sites and QnAs, i am so confused on how i can:

1. Find Deadlocks and what time they occured
2. How to identify what happened and a deadlock arrised.
3. And what is the query that caused a deadlock.

Is there any Query to extract such information?

Note that i have seen the tables

> sys.dm_tran_locks

> sys.dm_exec_requests

and still i do not understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way to find the deadlocks which have happened is with the use of the First Responder Kit from Brent Ozar.

This can be found here:
https://www.brentozar.com/first-aid/

When installed, you can run the `sp_blitzlock` command and see deadlock information.

https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/12/introducing-sp_blitzlock-troubleshooting-sql-server-deadlocks/

Another option, is to look in the ring buffer Martin suggested:
[https://www.sqlshack.com/monitoring-sql-server-deadlocks-using-the-system_health-extended-event/#:~:text=system_health%20event%20session.-,Extract%20SQL%20Server%20Deadlock%20information%20using%20T%2DSQL%20from%20the%20ring%20buffer%20target,-We%20can%20use](https://www.sqlshack.com/monitoring-sql-server-deadlocks-using-the-system_health-extended-event/#:%7E:text=system_health%20event%20session.-,Extract%20SQL%20Server%20Deadlock%20information%20using%20T%2DSQL%20from%20the%20ring%20buffer%20target,-We%20can%20use)

Comment: i have installed it and i can now see the procedure.  Although i name the database which the deadlock happened, i'm getting an empty list. exec sp_BlitzLock @DatabaseName = 'Mydb'

Comment: Do you see any deadlocks when you remove the @DatabaseName? Perhaps it is running from another database? (not sure if that is possible and how that is logged)

Comment: No, even after removing this, i'm getting an empty list.

Comment: You sure you are having deadlocks? What if you create a deadlock by yourself, will it return?

Comment: the deadlock occurred in production. i have taken a backup and restored the environment into a dev Server. is this the problem that i'm getting empty list? should i run it straight to production?

Comment: Yes, that is it indeed. You should run the script on the server where the deadlock arrises

Comment: Thank you for giving me your valuable time and information. i'm now in a better place to continue this journey!